# KnockoutJS help me when i change value input, list item had init not change value

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a grid with list of product {Name,Quatity,Price,Total}.I init `<input id='Price'>` with value 0, 
when change Quatity of one Product, automic computed Total = Quatity * Price, with `Price = $('#Price').val()` :

If grid init empty, i work correctly, But when i init Grid with some product and set `<input id='Price'>`with value 0, computed not work.

I want to automic computed when i change `<input id='Price'>`
Here is my Example in jsfiddle, but it not work.
http://jsfiddle.net/bd0ktx5r/5/

Comment: I guess it would be better if you take Price as an observable in your ViewModel and get the value from it.

Comment: i just fix demo in jsfiddle,you can try again, i want Price is a text input, when it change, all total will computed again

Comment: you can try it here : http://jsfiddle.net/bd0ktx5r/5/

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/bd0ktx5r/9/

I changed a bunch of stuff because at first I couldn't find the error, but when I opened my console I realized there were a lot of syntax errors and such.

The main thing I changed was the input field for price: I bound it against an observable I added to the viewmodel so your computed can respond to changes in it. For this to work, the price-observable had to be passed into the constructor of Product.

I also cleaned up your code a bit to hopefully make it more readable ander easier to understand.

The problem is that a ko.computed ONLY responds to changes in the observables it uses (dependencies). Because you used jQuery to get the value from the input-field, the ko.computed cannot know when the price has changed. The best way to avoid these errors is to ALWAYS use knockout, and not mix it with jQuery to get or set values.

Interesting bits of code:

```
var Product = function (product, priceObservable)
{
    var self = this;
    // omitted code
    self.Total = ko.computed(function () {
        // Here I use the observable passed into the function
        return priceObservable() === 0 ? 0 : (priceObservable() * self.Quatity()).toFixed(2);
    });
};

var ProductModel = function (json) {
    var self = this;
    self.price = ko.observable(3000); // 3000 can be any initial value
    self.products = ko.observableArray(json.map(function (item) {
        return new Product(item, self.price);
    }));
};

var productViewModel = new ProductModel(json);
ko.applyBindings(productViewModel);

<input type="text" data-bind="value: price, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
```

Comment: Here i try, but when change Price = 2000 and add new Product,but list of Product old still computed with Price =3000 http://jsfiddle.net/bd0ktx5r/8/

Comment: how can when i change value input text, all product change total

Comment: you changed it back to jQuery so now it's not working again. That's exactly what I said: don't use jQuery to read the value :)
The answer I gave uses an observable for the price-field and it works like you say.

Comment: self.price = ko.observable(value text box change); not self.price = ko.observable(3000);,can get value text box change by Knockout

Comment: The way you get `ko.observable(value text box change)` is through the binding in HTML: `<input type="text" data-bind="value: price, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />`. Also your ko.applyBindings now needs to apply to the WHOLE page: `ko.applyBindings(productViewModel);`. Please, look at my example again, it does all that and more. 3000 is just the initial value I set, it can be anything (or nothing) you want.

Comment: i know, but in my example, i add button add product,please fix my example, clear my jquery get set value, if i change value input text price, all products change value total, now in my example, each product has calculator old Price, thanks, Here link : http://jsfiddle.net/bd0ktx5r/8/